# How to properly format a JSON array | PHP

Tags: php, json

Essentially I have the following array with various values that are being passed through a function. The output of each needs to then be assembled into a JSON Array that looks like the following:

```
  "response": {
    "firstvalue": 4,
    "secondvalue": 1,
    "thirdvalue": "String Response 1",
    "fourthvalue": "String Response 2"
  }
```

**Code So Far:**

```
   <?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    
    $arrayvalues = 
    ["34jkw9k2k9w", 
    "k4otk320el01oeoo20", 
    "30f0w2l020wk3pld==", 
    "3c2x3123m4k43=="];
    
    foreach($arrayvalues as $item) {
        $decrypted = myFunction($item, $action = 'decrypt');
        $response["firstvalue"] = $decrypted;
        $response["secondvalue"] = $decrypted;
        $response["thirdvalue"] = $decrypted;
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    
    ?>
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Is there always just four values?

Comment: There is always a preset quantity of values, yes. 4 is just an example.

Comment: That answer was a bit unclear. Do you mean that there will always be the same amount of values, that the amount of values won't change? Or does your solution need to be flexible?

Comment: Yes there will always be the same amount of values, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$arrayvalues = 
["34jkw9k2k9w", 
"k4otk320el01oeoo20", 
"30f0w2l020wk3pld==", 
"3c2x3123m4k43=="];


// Is this necessary?
$keys = ['firstvalue', 'secondvalue', 'thirdvalue', 'fourthvalue'];

$result = [];
foreach($arrayvalues as $idx => $item) {
    $result[$keys[$idx]] = myFunction($item, $action = 'decrypt');
}

echo json_encode(['response' => $result], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

UPD: Added `response` nesting.

Comment: How can I get the `"response":` before the array starts?

Comment: @StephanieSmith, just add array nesting with `response` key for `$result` value. Watch it in changed answer.

Comment: A quick final question, how can I add one more static nested array at the end called `responsemessage` this is meant to following the first response array. Just doing `['error' => false, 'response' => $result, 'responsemessage' => 'Response Message']` is not working

Comment: Example `},
"responsemessage" : {
"message": "Response Message"`

Comment: @StephanieSmith, you mean `['error' => false, 'response' => $result, 'responsemessage' => ['message' => 'Response Message']]`?